# Error in Macro VBA. runtime error '-2147217900 (80040e14)' incorrect syntax error ')'

Tags: sql, excel, vba

This is the code I have can't figure why it is giving error. Debug brings me at  Conn.Execute (strSQL) this line. I tried couple of  fixes from online like removing quotes from around values but it didnt help

```
 If Not RS.EOF Then
                nObjectId = RS("OBJECTID")

                While x < 17
                    If tbProp(x, nGroup) <> "-1" Then
                        If Not IsError(.Cells(y, x)) Then
                            If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(y, x)) Or InStr(.Cells(y, x), "<") > 0 Then
                                strSQL = " INSERT INTO info_objectvalue(SCENARIOID ,PROPERTYID,PRODUCTID,CLIENTID,SERVICEID,OBJECTID,PROPERTYLOOKUP,PROPERTYVALUENUM)"
                                strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES(0 ," & tbProp(x, nGroup) & "," & nProductId & ",1,129," & nObjectId & ",0,0)"
                                Conn.Execute (strSQL)
                            Else
                                strSQL = " INSERT INTO info_objectvalue(SCENARIOID ,PROPERTYID,PRODUCTID,CLIENTID,SERVICEID,OBJECTID,PROPERTYLOOKUP,PROPERTYVALUENUM)"
                                strSQL = strSQL & " VALUES(0 ," & tbProp(x, nGroup) & "," & nProductId & ",1,129," & nObjectId & ",0," & Replace(.Cells(y, x), ",", ".") & ")"
                                Conn.Execute (strSQL)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                    x = x + 1
                Wend
            End If
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Wend
End With
```

Comment: There's a SQL syntax error in the SQL commands you are trying to execute.  Print out the `strSQL` variable to see what is in it, that's where the syntax error is.

Comment: ... we can't tell what the error is from here because we do not know what is in the variables that are being concatenated.  If you have the `strSQL` sql command and still cannot see what the syntax error ir, add that information to your question and we can try to answer it then.

Comment: Are all your variables filled?

Comment: @RBarryYoung strSQL is dim as string

Comment: @NeelPatel Yes, I know.  It's what's in `strSQL` that's the problem.  You code is trying to execute it as a SQL command to a database, but there is a SQL syntax error in that string.  So you need to look at/print out that string before you `Conn,Execute` it so that you (or we) can see what the syntax error is.

Comment: Right before your `Conn.Execute` line add `Debug.Print strSQL` and verify that the SQL you are passing the DB is structured correctly.  If possible, and you don't see any obvious problems, copy the SQL code from your immediate window into a query in your DB and verify that it works

Comment: @RBarryYoung 
debug.printINSERT INTO info_objectvalue(SCENARIOID ,PROPERTYID,PRODUCTID,CLIENTID,SERVICEID,OBJECTID,PROPERTYLOOKUP,PROPERTYVALUENUM) VALUES(0 ,1695,889025,1,129,2724,0,)

Comment: The error is right at the end there: `" ... 0,)"`.  You need to have a value between the comma and the parenthesis.  In all likelihood, the VBA code `& Replace(.Cells(y, x), ",", ".")` is returning an empty string (`""`) which is causing this problem.

Comment: @RBarryYoung  THanks for the help. I just put is empty check and it worked. one of them was empty value